# Why does Eclipse propose "Object" as default mapping type for datatype "Text"?

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jakarta-ee, dali

When generating JPA Entities from tables with Eclipse (Juno 4.2 for Java EE Developers) it proposes `Object` as default mapping type for properties I set to be `Text`.
That is quite annoying as I would have to set them all to `String` manually.
Has someone encountered that kind of problem and knows what to do? Is this a bug? Eclipse Indigo does not behave like that.

This is the `/runtime/vendors/MySql_5.1/MySql_5.1.xmi` from `org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.mysql.dbdefinition_1.0.4.v201109022331.jar`: (But as according to this file `Text` should be mapped to `String` this must be the wrong file - but how to find out the right one?)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<DBDefinition:DatabaseVendorDefinition xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:DBDefinition="http:///org/eclipse/datatools/modelbase/dbdefinition/dbdefinition.ecore" vendor="MySql" version="5.1" maximumIdentifierLength="64" joinSupported="true" tablespacesSupported="false" maximumCommentLength="60" schemaSupported="false" aliasSupported="true" SQLStatementSupported="true">
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="BIT_1" keyConstraintSupported="true"
maximumValue="1" minimumValue="0" primitiveType="SMALLINT" jdbcEnumType="-6"
javaClassName="byte">
    <defaultValueTypes>0</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>BIT</name>
    <name>BOOL</name>
    <name>BOOLEAN</name>
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="TINYINT_UNSIGNED"
keyConstraintSupported="true" maximumValue="255" minimumValue="0"
primitiveType="SMALLINT" jdbcEnumType="-6" javaClassName="byte">
    <defaultValueTypes>NULL</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>TINYINT UNSIGNED</name>
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="SMALLINT_UNSIGNED"
keyConstraintSupported="true" maximumValue="65535" minimumValue="0"
primitiveType="SMALLINT" jdbcEnumType="5" javaClassName="int">
    <defaultValueTypes>0</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>SMALLINT UNSIGNED</name>
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="MEDIUMINT_UNSIGNED"
keyConstraintSupported="true" maximumValue="16777215" minimumValue="0"
primitiveType="SMALLINT" jdbcEnumType="4" javaClassName="int">
    <defaultValueTypes>0</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED</name>
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="INTEGER_UNSIGNED"
keyConstraintSupported="true" maximumValue="4294967295" minimumValue="0"
primitiveType="INTEGER" jdbcEnumType="4" javaClassName="int">
    <defaultValueTypes>0</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>INTEGER UNSIGNED</name>
    <name>INT UNSIGNED</name>    
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="BIGINT_UNSIGNED"
keyConstraintSupported="true" identitySupported="true" primitiveType="BIGINT"
jdbcEnumType="-5" javaClassName="java.math.BigInteger">
    <defaultValueTypes>NULL</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>BIGINT UNSIGNED</name>
    <name>SERIAL</name>    
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="REAL_UNSIGNED"
keyConstraintSupported="true" primitiveType="REAL" jdbcEnumType="7"
javaClassName="float">
    <defaultValueTypes>NULL</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>REAL UNSIGNED</name>
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="DOUBLE_UNSIGNED_PRECISION"
keyConstraintSupported="true" primitiveType="DOUBLE_PRECISION" jdbcEnumType="8"
javaClassName="double">
    <defaultValueTypes>NULL</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>DOUBLE UNSIGNED</name>
    <name>DOUBLE UNSIGNED PRECISION</name>
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="FLOAT_UNSIGNED"
keyConstraintSupported="true" primitiveType="FLOAT" jdbcEnumType="6"
javaClassName="float">
    <defaultValueTypes>NULL</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>FLOAT UNSIGNED</name>
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="DECIMAL_UNSIGNED"
scaleSupported="true" precisionSupported="true" maximumPrecision="64"
keyConstraintSupported="true" primitiveType="DECIMAL" jdbcEnumType="3"
javaClassName="java.math.BigDecimal">
    <defaultValueTypes>NULL</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>DECIMAL UNSIGNED</name>
    <name>DEC UNSIGNED</name>
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
    <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="SMALLINT_2" keyConstraintSupported="true" maximumValue="127" minimumValue="-128" primitiveType="SMALLINT" jdbcEnumType="-6" javaClassName="byte">
    <defaultValueTypes>NULL</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>TINYINT</name>
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="SMALLINT_1" keyConstraintSupported="true" maximumValue="32767" minimumValue="-32768" primitiveType="SMALLINT" jdbcEnumType="5" javaClassName="short">
    <defaultValueTypes>NULL</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>SMALLINT</name>
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="INTEGER_2" keyConstraintSupported="true" maximumValue="8388607" minimumValue="-8388608" primitiveType="INTEGER" jdbcEnumType="4" javaClassName="int">
    <defaultValueTypes>NULL</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>MEDIUMINT</name>
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="INTEGER_1" keyConstraintSupported="true" identitySupported="true" maximumValue="2147483647" minimumValue="-2147483648" primitiveType="INTEGER" jdbcEnumType="4" javaClassName="int">
    <defaultValueTypes>NULL</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>INT</name>
    <name>INTEGER</name>
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="BIGINT_1" keyConstraintSupported="true" identitySupported="true" primitiveType="BIGINT" jdbcEnumType="-5" javaClassName="java.math.BigInteger">
    <defaultValueTypes>NULL</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>BIGINT</name>
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="REAL_1" keyConstraintSupported="true" primitiveType="REAL" jdbcEnumType="7" javaClassName="float">
    <defaultValueTypes>NULL</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>REAL</name>
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="DOUBLE_PRECISION_1" keyConstraintSupported="true" primitiveType="DOUBLE_PRECISION" jdbcEnumType="8" javaClassName="double">
    <defaultValueTypes>NULL</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>DOUBLE</name>
    <name>DOUBLE PRECISION</name>
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="FLOAT_1" keyConstraintSupported="true" primitiveType="FLOAT" jdbcEnumType="6" javaClassName="float">
    <defaultValueTypes>NULL</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>FLOAT</name>
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="DECIMAL_1" scaleSupported="true" precisionSupported="true" maximumPrecision="64" keyConstraintSupported="true" primitiveType="DECIMAL" jdbcEnumType="3" javaClassName="java.math.BigDecimal">
    <defaultValueTypes>NULL</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>DECIMAL</name>
    <name>DEC</name>
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="NUMERIC_1" scaleSupported="true" precisionSupported="true" maximumPrecision="64" keyConstraintSupported="true" primitiveType="NUMERIC" jdbcEnumType="2" javaClassName="java.math.BigDecimal">
    <defaultValueTypes>NULL</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>NUMERIC</name>
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="DATE_1" keyConstraintSupported="true" primitiveType="DATE" jdbcEnumType="91" javaClassName="java.sql.Date">
    <defaultValueTypes>NULL</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>DATE</name>
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="TIME_1" keyConstraintSupported="true" primitiveType="TIME" jdbcEnumType="92" javaClassName="java.sql.Time">
    <defaultValueTypes>NULL</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>TIME</name>
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="TIMESTAMP_1" keyConstraintSupported="true" primitiveType="TIMESTAMP" jdbcEnumType="93" javaClassName="java.sql.Timestamp">
    <defaultValueTypes>NULL</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>TIMESTAMP</name>
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="TIMESTAMP_2" keyConstraintSupported="true" primitiveType="TIMESTAMP" jdbcEnumType="93" javaClassName="java.util.Date">
    <defaultValueTypes>NULL</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>DATETIME</name>
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="CHARACTER_1" lengthSupported="true" keyConstraintSupported="true" maximumLength="255" jdbcEnumType="1" javaClassName="java.lang.String">
    <defaultValueTypes>NULL</defaultValueTypes>
    <defaultValueTypes>CURRENT_USER</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>CHAR</name>
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="CHARACTER_VARYING_1" lengthSupported="true" keyConstraintSupported="true" maximumLength="255" primitiveType="CHARACTER_VARYING" jdbcEnumType="12" javaClassName="java.lang.String">
    <defaultValueTypes>NULL</defaultValueTypes>
    <defaultValueTypes>CURRENT_USER</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>VARCHAR</name>
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="BINARY_LARGE_OBJECT_1" defaultSupported="false" maximumLength="256" primitiveType="BINARY_LARGE_OBJECT" jdbcEnumType="2004" javaClassName="java.sql.Blob">
    <defaultValueTypes>NULL</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>TINYBLOB</name>
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="BINARY_LARGE_OBJECT_2" defaultSupported="false" maximumLength="65536" primitiveType="BINARY_LARGE_OBJECT" jdbcEnumType="2004" javaClassName="java.sql.Blob">
    <defaultValueTypes>NULL</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>BLOB</name>
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="BINARY_LARGE_OBJECT_3" defaultSupported="false" maximumLength="16777216" primitiveType="BINARY_LARGE_OBJECT" jdbcEnumType="2004" javaClassName="java.sql.Blob">
    <defaultValueTypes>NULL</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>MEDIUMBLOB</name>
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="BINARY_LARGE_OBJECT_4" defaultSupported="false" primitiveType="BINARY_LARGE_OBJECT" jdbcEnumType="2004" javaClassName="java.sql.Blob">
    <defaultValueTypes>NULL</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>LONGBLOB</name>
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="CHARACTER_LARGE_OBJECT_1" keyConstraintSupported="true" defaultSupported="false" maximumLength="256" primitiveType="CHARACTER_LARGE_OBJECT" jdbcEnumType="2005" javaClassName="java.lang.String">
    <defaultValueTypes>NULL</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>TINYTEXT</name>
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="CHARACTER_LARGE_OBJECT_2" keyConstraintSupported="true" defaultSupported="false" maximumLength="65536" primitiveType="CHARACTER_LARGE_OBJECT" jdbcEnumType="2005" javaClassName="java.lang.String">
    <defaultValueTypes>NULL</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>TEXT</name>
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="CHARACTER_LARGE_OBJECT_3" keyConstraintSupported="true" defaultSupported="false" maximumLength="16777216" primitiveType="CHARACTER_LARGE_OBJECT" jdbcEnumType="2005" javaClassName="java.lang.String">
    <defaultValueTypes>NULL</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>MEDIUMTEXT</name>
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="CHARACTER_LARGE_OBJECT_4" keyConstraintSupported="true" defaultSupported="false" primitiveType="CHARACTER_LARGE_OBJECT" jdbcEnumType="2005" javaClassName="java.lang.String">
    <defaultValueTypes>NULL</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>LONGTEXT</name>
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="ENUM" keyConstraintSupported="false" primitiveType="CHARACTER_VARYING" jdbcEnumType="12" javaClassName="java.lang.String">
    <defaultValueTypes>NULL</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>ENUM</name>
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="DATE_2" keyConstraintSupported="true" primitiveType="DATE" jdbcEnumType="91" javaClassName="java.sql.Date">
    <defaultValueTypes>NULL</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>YEAR</name>
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="BINARY_1" lengthSupported="true" keyConstraintSupported="true" maximumLength="255" lengthUnit="BYTE" primitiveType="BINARY" jdbcEnumType="-2" javaClassName="byte[]">
    <defaultValueTypes>NULL</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>BINARY</name>
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <predefinedDataTypeDefinitions xmi:id="BINARY_VARYING_1" lengthSupported="true" keyConstraintSupported="true" maximumLength="255" primitiveType="BINARY_VARYING" lengthUnit="BYTE" jdbcEnumType="-3" javaClassName="byte[]">
    <defaultValueTypes>NULL</defaultValueTypes>
    <name>VARBINARY</name>
  </predefinedDataTypeDefinitions>
  <storedProcedureDefinition/>
  <triggerDefinition/>
  <columnDefinition maximumIdentifierLength="64" identitySupported="true" identityIncrementSupported="true"/>
  <constraintDefinition clusteredPrimaryKeySupported="true" clusteredUniqueConstraintSupported="true" primaryKeyNullable="true" uniqueKeyNullable="true">
    <parentUpdateDRIRuleType>RESTRICT</parentUpdateDRIRuleType>
    <parentUpdateDRIRuleType>CASCADE</parentUpdateDRIRuleType>
    <parentUpdateDRIRuleType>SET_NULL</parentUpdateDRIRuleType>
    <parentUpdateDRIRuleType>NO_ACTION</parentUpdateDRIRuleType>
    <parentDeleteDRIRuleType>RESTRICT</parentDeleteDRIRuleType>
    <parentDeleteDRIRuleType>CASCADE</parentDeleteDRIRuleType>
    <parentDeleteDRIRuleType>SET_NULL</parentDeleteDRIRuleType>
    <parentDeleteDRIRuleType>NO_ACTION</parentDeleteDRIRuleType>
  </constraintDefinition>
  <indexDefinition maximumIdentifierLength="64"/>
  <tableDefinition maximumIdentifierLength="64"/>
  <udtDefinition/>
  <queryDefinition identifierQuoteString="`" hostVariableMarker="@" hostVariableMarkerSupported="true"/>
  <viewDefinition maximumIdentifierLength="64" checkOptionLevelsSupported="true"/>
  <SQLSyntaxDefinition>
    <keywords>ACCESSIBLE</keywords>
    <keywords>ADD</keywords>
    <keywords>ALGORITHM</keywords>
    <keywords>ALL</keywords>
    <keywords>ALTER</keywords>
    <keywords>ANALYZE</keywords>
    <keywords>AND</keywords>
    <keywords>AS</keywords>
    <keywords>ASC</keywords>
    <keywords>ASENSITIVE</keywords>
    <keywords>BEFORE</keywords>
    <keywords>BETWEEN</keywords>
    <keywords>BIGINT</keywords>
    <keywords>BINARY</keywords>
    <keywords>BLOB</keywords>
    <keywords>BOTH</keywords>
    <keywords>BY</keywords>
    <keywords>CALL</keywords>
    <keywords>CASCADE</keywords>
    <keywords>CASE</keywords>
    <keywords>CHANGE</keywords>
    <keywords>CHAR</keywords>
    <keywords>CHARACTER</keywords>
    <keywords>CHECK</keywords>
    <keywords>CHECKSUM</keywords>
    <keywords>COLLATE</keywords>
    <keywords>COLUMN</keywords>
    <keywords>COMMENT</keywords>
    <keywords>CONDITION</keywords>
    <keywords>CONNECTION</keywords>
    <keywords>CONSTRAINT</keywords>
    <keywords>CONTINUE</keywords>
    <keywords>CONVERT</keywords>
    <keywords>CREATE</keywords>
    <keywords>CROSS</keywords>
    <keywords>CURRENT_DATE</keywords>
    <keywords>CURRENT_TIME</keywords>
    <keywords>CURRENT_TIMESTAMP</keywords>
    <keywords>CURRENT_USER</keywords>
    <keywords>CURSOR</keywords>
    <keywords>DATABASE</keywords>
    <keywords>DATABASES</keywords>
    <keywords>DAY_HOUR</keywords>
    <keywords>DAY_MICROSECOND</keywords>
    <keywords>DAY_MINUTE</keywords>
    <keywords>DAY_SECOND</keywords>
    <keywords>DEC</keywords>
    <keywords>DECIMAL</keywords>
    <keywords>DECLARE</keywords>
    <keywords>DEFAULT</keywords>
    <keywords>DEFINER</keywords>
    <keywords>DELAYED</keywords>
    <keywords>DELETE</keywords>
    <keywords>DESC</keywords>
    <keywords>DESCRIBE</keywords>
    <keywords>DETERMINISTIC</keywords>
    <keywords>DISTINCT</keywords>
    <keywords>DISTINCTROW</keywords>
    <keywords>DIV</keywords>
    <keywords>DOUBLE</keywords>
    <keywords>DROP</keywords>
    <keywords>DUAL</keywords>
    <keywords>EACH</keywords>
    <keywords>ELSE</keywords>
    <keywords>ELSEIF</keywords>
    <keywords>ENCLOSED</keywords>
    <keywords>ESCAPED</keywords>
    <keywords>EXISTS</keywords>
    <keywords>EXIT</keywords>
    <keywords>EXPLAIN</keywords>
    <keywords>FALSE</keywords>
    <keywords>FETCH</keywords>
    <keywords>FLOAT</keywords>
    <keywords>FLOAT4</keywords>
    <keywords>FLOAT8</keywords>
    <keywords>FOR</keywords>
    <keywords>FORCE</keywords>
    <keywords>FOREIGN</keywords>
    <keywords>FROM</keywords>
    <keywords>FULLTEXT</keywords>
    <keywords>GOTO</keywords>
    <keywords>GRANT</keywords>
    <keywords>GROUP</keywords>
    <keywords>HAVING</keywords>
    <keywords>HIGH_PRIORITY</keywords>
    <keywords>HOUR_MICROSECOND</keywords>
    <keywords>HOUR_MINUTE</keywords>
    <keywords>HOUR_SECOND</keywords>
    <keywords>IF</keywords>
    <keywords>IGNORE</keywords>
    <keywords>IN</keywords>
    <keywords>INDEX</keywords>
    <keywords>INFILE</keywords>
    <keywords>INNER</keywords>
    <keywords>INOUT</keywords>
    <keywords>INSENSITIVE</keywords>
    <keywords>INSERT</keywords>
    <keywords>INT</keywords>
    <keywords>INT1</keywords>
    <keywords>INT2</keywords>
    <keywords>INT3</keywords>
    <keywords>INT4</keywords>
    <keywords>INT8</keywords>
    <keywords>INTEGER</keywords>
    <keywords>INTERVAL</keywords>
    <keywords>INTO</keywords>
    <keywords>INVOKER</keywords>
    <keywords>IS</keywords>
    <keywords>ITERATE</keywords>
    <keywords>JOIN</keywords>
    <keywords>KEY_BLOCK_SIZE</keywords>
    <keywords>KEY</keywords>
    <keywords>KEYS</keywords>
    <keywords>KILL</keywords>
    <keywords>LABEL</keywords>
    <keywords>LEADING</keywords>
    <keywords>LEAVE</keywords>
    <keywords>LEFT</keywords>
    <keywords>LIKE</keywords>
    <keywords>LIMIT</keywords>
    <keywords>LINEAR</keywords>
    <keywords>LINES</keywords>
    <keywords>LOAD</keywords>
    <keywords>LOCALTIME</keywords>
    <keywords>LOCALTIMESTAMP</keywords>
    <keywords>LOCK</keywords>
    <keywords>LONG</keywords>
    <keywords>LONGBLOB</keywords>
    <keywords>LONGTEXT</keywords>
    <keywords>LOOP</keywords>
    <keywords>LOW_PRIORITY</keywords>
    <keywords>MASTER_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT</keywords>
    <keywords>MATCH</keywords>
    <keywords>MAX_ROWS</keywords>
    <keywords>MEDIUMBLOB</keywords>
    <keywords>MEDIUMINT</keywords>
    <keywords>MEDIUMTEXT</keywords>
    <keywords>MERGE</keywords>
    <keywords>MIDDLEINT</keywords>
    <keywords>MIN_ROWS</keywords>
    <keywords>MINUTE_MICROSECOND</keywords>
    <keywords>MINUTE_SECOND</keywords>
    <keywords>MOD</keywords>
    <keywords>MODIFIES</keywords>
    <keywords>NATURAL</keywords>
    <keywords>NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG</keywords>
    <keywords>NOT</keywords>
    <keywords>NULL</keywords>
    <keywords>NUMERIC</keywords>
    <keywords>ON</keywords>
    <keywords>OPTIMIZE</keywords>
    <keywords>OPTION</keywords>
    <keywords>OPTIONALLY</keywords>
    <keywords>OR</keywords>
    <keywords>ORDER</keywords>
    <keywords>OUT</keywords>
    <keywords>OUTER</keywords>
    <keywords>OUTFILE</keywords>
    <keywords>PRECISION</keywords>
    <keywords>PRIMARY</keywords>
    <keywords>PROCEDURE</keywords>
    <keywords>PURGE</keywords>
    <keywords>RANGE</keywords>
    <keywords>READ</keywords>
    <keywords>READ_ONLY</keywords>
    <keywords>READ_WRITE</keywords>
    <keywords>READ</keywords>
    <keywords>READS</keywords>
    <keywords>REAL</keywords>
    <keywords>REFERENCES</keywords>
    <keywords>REGEXP</keywords>
    <keywords>RELEASE</keywords>
    <keywords>RENAME</keywords>
    <keywords>REPEAT</keywords>
    <keywords>REPLACE</keywords>
    <keywords>REQUIRE</keywords>
    <keywords>RESTRICT</keywords>
    <keywords>RETURN</keywords>
    <keywords>REVOKE</keywords>
    <keywords>RIGHT</keywords>
    <keywords>RLIKE</keywords>
    <keywords>ROW_FORMAT</keywords>
    <keywords>SCHEMA</keywords>
    <keywords>SCHEMAS</keywords>
    <keywords>SECOND_MICROSECOND</keywords>
    <keywords>SELECT</keywords>
    <keywords>SENSITIVE</keywords>
    <keywords>SEPARATOR</keywords>
    <keywords>SET</keywords>
    <keywords>SHOW</keywords>
    <keywords>SMALLINT</keywords>
    <keywords>SONAME</keywords>
    <keywords>SPATIAL</keywords>
    <keywords>SPECIFIC</keywords>
    <keywords>SQL</keywords>
    <keywords>SQL_BIG_RESULT</keywords>
    <keywords>SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS</keywords>
    <keywords>SQL_SECURITY</keywords>
    <keywords>SQL_SMALL_RESULT</keywords>
    <keywords>SQL</keywords>
    <keywords>SQLEXCEPTION</keywords>
    <keywords>SQLSTATE</keywords>
    <keywords>SQLWARNING</keywords>
    <keywords>SSL</keywords>
    <keywords>STARTING</keywords>
    <keywords>STRAIGHT_JOIN</keywords>
    <keywords>TABLE</keywords>
    <keywords>TEMPTABLE</keywords>
    <keywords>TERMINATED</keywords>
    <keywords>THEN</keywords>
    <keywords>TINYBLOB</keywords>
    <keywords>TINYINT</keywords>
    <keywords>TINYTEXT</keywords>
    <keywords>TO</keywords>
    <keywords>TRAILING</keywords>
    <keywords>TRIGGER</keywords>
    <keywords>TRUE</keywords>
    <keywords>UNDEFINED</keywords>
    <keywords>UNDO</keywords>
    <keywords>UNION</keywords>
    <keywords>UNIQUE</keywords>
    <keywords>UNLOCK</keywords>
    <keywords>UNSIGNED</keywords>
    <keywords>UPDATE</keywords>
    <keywords>UPGRADE</keywords>
    <keywords>USAGE</keywords>
    <keywords>USE</keywords>
    <keywords>USING</keywords>
    <keywords>UTC_DATE</keywords>
    <keywords>UTC_TIME</keywords>
    <keywords>UTC_TIMESTAMP</keywords>
    <keywords>VALUES</keywords>
    <keywords>VARBINARY</keywords>
    <keywords>VARCHAR</keywords>
    <keywords>VARCHARACTER</keywords>
    <keywords>VARYING</keywords>
    <keywords>WHEN</keywords>
    <keywords>WHERE</keywords>
    <keywords>WHILE</keywords>
    <keywords>WITH</keywords>
    <keywords>WRITE</keywords>
    <keywords>XOR</keywords>
    <keywords>YEAR_MONTH</keywords>
    <keywords>ZEROFILL</keywords>
    <operators>:=</operators>
    <operators>||</operators>
    <operators>OR</operators>
    <operators>XOR</operators>
    <operators>&amp;&amp;</operators>
    <operators>AND</operators>
    <operators>NOT</operators>
    <operators>BETWEEN</operators>
    <operators>CASE</operators>
    <operators>WHEN</operators>
    <operators>THEN</operators>
    <operators>ELSE</operators>
    <operators>=</operators>
    <operators>&lt;=></operators>
    <operators>>=</operators>
    <operators>></operators>
    <operators>&lt;=</operators>
    <operators>&lt;</operators>
    <operators>&lt;></operators>
    <operators>!=</operators>
    <operators>IS</operators>
    <operators>LIKE</operators>
    <operators>REGEXP</operators>
    <operators>IN</operators>
    <operators>|</operators>
    <operators>&amp;</operators>
    <operators>&lt;&lt;</operators>
    <operators>>></operators>
    <operators>-</operators>
    <operators>+</operators>
    <operators>*</operators>
    <operators>/</operators>
    <operators>DIV</operators>
    <operators>%</operators>
    <operators>MOD</operators>
    <operators>^</operators>
    <operators>~</operators>
    <operators>!</operators>
    <operators>BINARY</operators>
    <operators>COLLATE</operators>
  </SQLSyntaxDefinition>
</DBDefinition:DatabaseVendorDefinition>
```

My SQL:

```
CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;
USE `mydb`;
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.5.16, for Win32 (x86)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: mydb
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.5.28

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `flour`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `flour`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `flour` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` text,
  `grain_size` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `flour`
--

LOCK TABLES `flour` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `flour` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `flour` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `bread`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `bread`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `bread` (
  `name` text,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `flour_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_bread_flour_idx` (`flour_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_bread_flour` FOREIGN KEY (`flour_id`) REFERENCES `flour` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `bread`
--

LOCK TABLES `bread` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `bread` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `bread` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2012-11-13  8:53:50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dali (the part of Eclipse that generates JPA entities) uses DTP (another part of Eclipse) to determine the Java attribute type for a particular data type. These mappings are database platform-specific and are specified in `.xmi` files in various DTP plug-ins.

For example, in Juno, for PostgreSQL, the data type `ABSTIME` is mapped to the Java type `java.lang.Object` in the file
`/runtime/vendors/postgresql/postgresql_8.x.xmi`
in the plug-in jar
`./plugins/org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.postgresql.dbdefinition_1.0.2.v201110070445.jar`.

Depending on your database platform and what other plug-ins you have installed, these settings could have changed between Indigo and Juno. You can extract the appropriate .xmi file, edit it, and return it to its jar and this should alter how entities are generated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I compared the `vendors` from Juno's and Indigo's `org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.mysql.dbdefinition_1.0.4.v201109022331.jar` - they match exactly. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Lester [It looks like some reviewers rejected your modifications. Oh well.] I have been unable to reproduce this behavior with Juno and MySQL 5.1. When you say "It was a Juno bug", are you talking about a specific Eclipse bug on Bugzilla? If so, maybe we can mention that here.

Comment: I could not find the exact bug on bugzilla. I noticed that the problem only shows up when there are foreign keys in the sql. I created a dump (see edited question) with which you should be able to reproduce. Just try to create entities from those tables and look for the default mapping type of e.g. table: "bread"; key: "name" (should be String). Cancel and do it again from "create entities from tables"... now "name" mapping type should be Object instead of String. Once I only got that result only on third time, probably I missed something - maybe its important to refresh tables

Comment: @Lester I have been unable to reproduce your problem; but if you can document steps to reliably reproduce it, please file a bug against Dali at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Dali%20JPA%20Tools