# Changing default field types when generating entities from tables

Tags: eclipse, jpa-2.0, dali

Using Eclipse Dali tools to "[generate entities from tables](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/docs/3.2/user_guide/tasks006.htm#BABBAGFI)" but I want to change the default table column / entity field mappings.

For example when column type is **int** the tools generate the following mapping.

```
@Column(name="QUANTITY")
private int quantity;
```

But when the quantity is nullable, it makes problems during the validation phase, so I change it to:

```
@Column(name="QUANTITY",  columnDefinition="int")
private BigDecimal quantity;
```

Can this be configured globally?

Comment: You might look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300997/why-does-eclipse-propose-object-as-default-mapping-type-for-datatype-text/13310935#13310935

Comment: I understand that these are hard coded per database type and not configurable and need to modify plugin jars to accomplish. Thanx