# Generate JPA entities with wrapper classes instead of primitives in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jpa

I'm currently using Eclipse Luna for J2EE Developers to generate JPA entities from a schema.  The generated entities are being created with primitives (int) instead of wrappers (Integer) which is an issue for nullable fields.  Is there a way to change this?  There doesn't seem to be an option for it in the wizard and I have had no luck in my search so far.

Here is a snippet of a generated class as an example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="facility")
@NamedQuery(name="Facility.findAll", query="SELECT f FROM Facility f")
public class Facility implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name="census_code")
private String censusCode;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date created;

private Timestamp modified;

private String name;

@Column(name="portal_id")
private int portalId;

@Column(name="short_name")
private String shortName;

...

}
```

Obviously id should remain a primitive but in this case portalId should be  using the wrapper class.

Any suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: As I remember, in jpa it doesn't matter what you use as fields in jpa entity, primitives or wrappers.

Comment: Is there some reason why you care?  Generally autoboxing will make things pretty much "just work."  Unless the columns are nullable, you should be fine with the primitives.

Comment: Yes, there are a number of columns across the whole database that are nullable and thus primitives won't suffice. The code posted above was just a snippet of one of the classes auto generated by Eclipse.

Comment: How Eclipse generates the types for your fields is determined by DTP mappings. See the [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300997/why-does-eclipse-propose-object-as-default-mapping-type-for-datatype-text).