# Why eclipselink convert BIGINT to string type?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I am using EclipseLink 2.6 and MySQL 5.
In the database, I design a table named User which has a `id` column as BIGINT datatype.

Then I use Eclipse to generate entity class from the table.
After generating, the entity class User has the id field as String, which I would have expected as long type.
I tried to perform CRUD operations and all worked just fine.
Why a String type can be mapped to a BIGINT type.

Comment: The automatic class/mapping generation are not always working 100% perfect. And yes, it's possible to convert from/to String/Bigint with no real problems, it will just be slower than using the same datatype on both sides

Comment: This is not eclipse link problem in my opinion. It is more of an eclispe JPA plugin issue

Comment: Dali, the Eclipse JPA plug-in, uses DTP to determine what Java type to generate for a specific database type. There is a bit more information in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300997/why-does-eclipse-propose-object-as-default-mapping-type-for-datatype-text?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Thanks Brian for the link. It is helpful