# How do I mapped an oracle table column of type NVARCHAR2(100) to JPA fields?

Tags: oracle, jpa

I have an oracle table that contains 4 columns, one of them is a localizedText of type NVARCHAR2(100).

When I import the table using Eclipse (MARS) environment JPA class, it creates a class but then create a field private Object localizedText. Which errors out when i run the code since during runtime it does not accept a field of type object.

How do I change the private Object localizedText; definition to work with an oracle NVarChar2(100) type column?

Thanks

Comment: since Eclipse Dali doesn't have a clue about NVARCHAR JDBC type, so just puts Object.

Comment: Actually, it's not Dali; but the DTP (Data Tools Platform) plug-in that is handling the mapping. Here is a related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300997/why-does-eclipse-propose-object-as-default-mapping-type-for-datatype-text/13310935#13310935

Answer (score 1):

Define the attribute as String in your JPA class