# Entity from Table

Tags: eclipse, jpa, dali

I am using `"JPA Entities from table option"` in order to get the entity generated form database tables, all the setup is correct even JPA is generating the entity for the database tables, but when my table consist the column type XML..

> "MAPSETDETAIL" XML

the entity not getting generated. Any one have any idea. I am using JPA prespective from eclipse LUNA for entity generation.

**Error in workspace .metadata/.log file.....**

```
>     !MESSAGE Error Generating Entities
>     !STACK 0
>     org.apache.velocity.exception.MethodInvocationException: Invocation of method 'getImportStatements' in  class
> org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.ORMGenTable threw exception
> java.lang.NullPointerException @ main.java.vm[7,9]
>       at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTIdentifier.execute(ASTIdentifier.java:205)
>       at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTReference.execute(ASTReference.java:203)
>       at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTReference.render(ASTReference.java:294)
>       at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.SimpleNode.render(SimpleNode.java:318)
>       at org.apache.velocity.Template.merge(Template.java:254)
>       at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.mergeTemplate(VelocityEngine.java:508)
>       at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.mergeTemplate(VelocityEngine.java:473)
>       at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.PackageGenerator.generateJavaFile(PackageGenerator.java:333)
>       at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.PackageGenerator.generateClass(PackageGenerator.java:310)
>       at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.PackageGenerator.generateInternal(PackageGenerator.java:132)
>       at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.PackageGenerator.doGenerate(PackageGenerator.java:106)
>       at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.PackageGenerator.generate(PackageGenerator.java:82)
>       at org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.ui.internal.wizards.gen.GenerateEntitiesFromSchemaWizard$GenerateEntitiesJob.runInWorkspace(GenerateEntitiesFromSchemaWizard.java:285)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
>     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**Complete Stack Trace....**

```
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2016-08-31 00:21:55.373 !MESSAGE
> Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of
> native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level Git settings which
> might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git
> installation directory. The most important of these settings is
> core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true
> in this system level configuration. The Git installation location can
> be configured on the Team > Git > Configuration preference page's
> 'System Settings' tab. This warning can be switched off on the Team >
> Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
> 
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2016-08-31 00:21:55.375 !MESSAGE
> Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following
> directory will be used to store the Git user global configuration and
> to define the default location to store repositories:
> 'C:\Users\Katara'. If this is not correct please set the HOME
> environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows
> and EGit might behave differently since they see different
> configuration options. This warning can be switched off on the Team >
> Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
> 
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.ui 4 10001 2016-08-31 00:47:41.172 !MESSAGE
> Internal Error !STACK 0 org.eclipse.jface.text.BadLocationException
>   at
> org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.addPosition(AbstractDocument.java:355)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.SynchronizableDocument.addPosition(SynchronizableDocument.java:236)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.SemanticHighlightingPresenter.updatePresentation(SemanticHighlightingPresenter.java:414)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.SemanticHighlightingPresenter$1.run(SemanticHighlightingPresenter.java:347)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)   at
> org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:136)
>   at
> org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4147)
>   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3764)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
>   at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
>   at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)  at
> org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
>   at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
>   at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)     at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)  at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)     at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
> 
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen 4 0 2016-08-31 02:12:51.390 !MESSAGE
> Error Generating Entities !STACK 0
> org.apache.velocity.exception.MethodInvocationException: Invocation of
> method 'getImportStatements' in  class
> org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.ORMGenTable threw exception
> java.lang.NullPointerException @ main.java.vm[7,9]    at
> org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTIdentifier.execute(ASTIdentifier.java:205)
>   at
> org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTReference.execute(ASTReference.java:203)
>   at
> org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTReference.render(ASTReference.java:294)
>   at
> org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.SimpleNode.render(SimpleNode.java:318)
>   at org.apache.velocity.Template.merge(Template.java:254)    at
> org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.mergeTemplate(VelocityEngine.java:508)
>   at
> org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.mergeTemplate(VelocityEngine.java:473)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.PackageGenerator.generateJavaFile(PackageGenerator.java:333)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.PackageGenerator.generateClass(PackageGenerator.java:310)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.PackageGenerator.generateInternal(PackageGenerator.java:132)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.PackageGenerator.doGenerate(PackageGenerator.java:106)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.PackageGenerator.generate(PackageGenerator.java:82)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.ui.internal.wizards.gen.GenerateEntitiesFromSchemaWizard$GenerateEntitiesJob.runInWorkspace(GenerateEntitiesFromSchemaWizard.java:285)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
>   at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54) Caused
> by: java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> org.eclipse.jpt.common.utility.internal.StringTools.indexOfWhitespace(StringTools.java:697)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jpt.common.utility.internal.StringTools.removeAllWhitespace(StringTools.java:687)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jpt.common.utility.internal.TypeDeclarationTools.className(TypeDeclarationTools.java:215)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.db.internal.DTPColumnWrapper.getJavaType(DTPColumnWrapper.java:140)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.db.internal.DTPColumnWrapper.getJavaType(DTPColumnWrapper.java:125)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.db.internal.DTPColumnWrapper.getJavaTypeDeclaration(DTPColumnWrapper.java:119)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.util.DTPUtil.getJavaType(DTPUtil.java:72)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.BaseEntityGenCustomizer.getPropertyTypeFromColumn(BaseEntityGenCustomizer.java:90)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.ORMGenColumn.getPropertyType(ORMGenColumn.java:184)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.ORMGenTable.buildColumnTypesMap(ORMGenTable.java:204)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.ORMGenTable.getImportStatements(ORMGenTable.java:138)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:589)     at
> org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.PropertyExecutor.execute(PropertyExecutor.java:137)
>   at
> org.apache.velocity.util.introspection.UberspectImpl$VelGetterImpl.invoke(UberspectImpl.java:350)
>   at
> org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTIdentifier.execute(ASTIdentifier.java:180)
>   ... 14 more
> 
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen 4 0 2016-08-31 02:13:52.696 !MESSAGE
> Error Generating Entities !STACK 0
> org.apache.velocity.exception.MethodInvocationException: Invocation of
> method 'getImportStatements' in  class
> org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.ORMGenTable threw exception
> java.lang.NullPointerException @ main.java.vm[7,9]    at
> org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTIdentifier.execute(ASTIdentifier.java:205)
>   at
> org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTReference.execute(ASTReference.java:203)
>   at
> org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTReference.render(ASTReference.java:294)
>   at
> org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.SimpleNode.render(SimpleNode.java:318)
>   at org.apache.velocity.Template.merge(Template.java:254)    at
> org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.mergeTemplate(VelocityEngine.java:508)
>   at
> org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.mergeTemplate(VelocityEngine.java:473)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.PackageGenerator.generateJavaFile(PackageGenerator.java:333)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.PackageGenerator.generateClass(PackageGenerator.java:310)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.PackageGenerator.generateInternal(PackageGenerator.java:132)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.PackageGenerator.doGenerate(PackageGenerator.java:106)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.PackageGenerator.generate(PackageGenerator.java:82)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.ui.internal.wizards.gen.GenerateEntitiesFromSchemaWizard$GenerateEntitiesJob.runInWorkspace(GenerateEntitiesFromSchemaWizard.java:285)
>   at
> org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
>   at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54) Caused
> by: java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> org.eclipse.jpt.common.utility.internal.StringTools.indexOfWhitespace(StringTools.java:697)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jpt.common.utility.internal.StringTools.removeAllWhitespace(StringTools.java:687)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jpt.common.utility.internal.TypeDeclarationTools.className(TypeDeclarationTools.java:215)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.db.internal.DTPColumnWrapper.getJavaType(DTPColumnWrapper.java:140)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.db.internal.DTPColumnWrapper.getJavaType(DTPColumnWrapper.java:125)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.db.internal.DTPColumnWrapper.getJavaTypeDeclaration(DTPColumnWrapper.java:119)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.util.DTPUtil.getJavaType(DTPUtil.java:72)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.BaseEntityGenCustomizer.getPropertyTypeFromColumn(BaseEntityGenCustomizer.java:90)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.ORMGenColumn.getPropertyType(ORMGenColumn.java:184)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.ORMGenTable.buildColumnTypesMap(ORMGenTable.java:204)
>   at
> org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.gen.internal.ORMGenTable.getImportStatements(ORMGenTable.java:138)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:589)     at
> org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.PropertyExecutor.execute(PropertyExecutor.java:137)
>   at
> org.apache.velocity.util.introspection.UberspectImpl$VelGetterImpl.invoke(UberspectImpl.java:350)
>   at
> org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTIdentifier.execute(ASTIdentifier.java:180)
>   ... 14 more
```

Comment: You might check the Eclipse workspace log file (.metadata/.log) for any exceptions that look related.

Comment: I have updated the logs from .metadata/.log file.

Comment: So, yes, it looks like Dali is encountering an unexpected exception and that is killing your entity generation. All we can hope for is a workaround that would allow you to avoid that NPE. But, to even begin to figure that out, we need the stack trace for the NPE; which should be the lines iun the log file just following what you have posted. :-) In fact, there could be a number of nested exception stack traces in that log entry. Can you post all the lines up to the next "!MESSAGE ..." line?

Comment: Sure i have updated the whole stack trace.

Comment: Dali is using DTP to map your column's XML datatype to a Java type for the corresponding Java attribute (field/property). It looks like DTP does have some metadata for the XML datatype, but it does not have a Java type mapping; so it returns `null`, which Dali is not expecting. These mapping values are defined in various .xml files. Here is a discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13300997/why-does-eclipse-propose-object-as-default-mapping-type-for-datatype-text/13310935#13310935

Comment: I am using i series db2 databases and able to find the .xmi files inside org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ibm.db2.luw.dbdefinition_1.0.7.v201405302027.jar\runtime\vendors\  , but i have confused what to edit as both the tags for XML & CLOB data types are available inside the XMI files. And these jars are provide by the vendors so  i am expecting these are correct one's. Anywhere else i can edit so the i can generate the reverse code file for CLOB & XML column type.

Comment: I don't think the files are not provided by the vendors. Given the number of errors people have encountered in them, I think they are educated guesses made by the DTP developers, years ago. Assuming your data type is "XML", I'm pretty sure you need to edit the data type definition for "XML"; since Dali simply uses the data type name to fetch the mapping. I see the "DB2 UDB_10.5.xml" file is missing any sort of javaClassName attribute for the "XML" data type. And it looks very different from all the other data types. :-(